# Unable to connect WPA3 enabled wifi using node-wifi npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, wifi

I'm currently attempting to connect to a WiFi network that's secured with WPA3 encryption using the 'node-wifi' package. Unfortunately, my attempts have been unsuccessful so far, and it appears that 'node-wifi' doesn't support WPA3. You can find more information about 'node-wifi' on its npm page at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wifi. Is there a possible solution or workaround to resolve this issue and enable a successful connection to the WPA3-secured network?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue previously and here is the solution for it. you can user another package which same codebase as node-wifi but just WPA3 issue is fixed in this new package.

```
npm i node-wifi-2.0
```